# Can Snowflake run pandas manipulation?

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I asked this question to chatGPT and got the following answer, I think it is wrong, but can someone confirm this too?

> i dont want to load the data into my machine, rather i want the query and execution of the dataframe manipulation to be ran from snowflake engine itself, so that i don't consume my local machine's memory and cpu. can I do that with pandas on snowflake?

Answer from chatGPT:

> Yes, you can execute Pandas dataframe manipulation directly in Snowflake using Snowpark without loading the data into your local machine's memory.
>
> Snowpark allows you to use the Pandas API on data residing in
> Snowflake and execute the computation in the Snowflake engine. This
> means that the data remains in Snowflake, and you do not need to
> download or upload it to your local machine.
>
> Here's an example of how to execute a Pandas dataframe manipulation in
> Snowflake using Snowpark:

```
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

# Connect to Snowflake
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='<your_username>',
    password='<your_password>',
    account='<your_account>',
    warehouse='<your_warehouse>',
    database='<your_database>',
    schema='<your_schema>'
)

# Load data from Snowflake into a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM my_table', conn)

# Perform data manipulation using Pandas API
df['new_column'] = df['old_column'] * 2

# Write the manipulated data back to Snowflake
write_pandas(conn=conn, df=df, table_name='my_table', schema='<your_schema>')
```

> In the above example, the write_pandas function writes the Pandas
> dataframe df back to Snowflake, with the table_name and schema
> parameters specifying where to write the data.
>
> By using Snowpark and the snowflake.connector.pandas_tools package,
> you can perform data manipulation using Pandas API on data residing in
> Snowflake and execute the computation in the Snowflake engine, without
> the need to load the data into your local machine's memory.

From what I understand, the Snowflake Connector is not related to Snowpark, and doing `pd.read_sql_query` is reading into local memory, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `read_sql_query` will pull all the data onto your local machine, do manipulation there, and then push the data back to snowflake via `write_pandas`.

If you want actual pushdown of pandas operators into Snowflake/SQL you could take a look at [Ponder.io](https://ponder.io/). They are a paid solution that does exactly this. Their founder is the author of the OOS projet [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) which is a way to scale pandas out to a (ray-backed) server cluster.